# how to get the first 8 characters from the first column of a table and how to import it from postgresql using python;

Tags: python, postgresql

First two lines of My Data(Four columns) will be like

```
"Value_Name" "Input1" "Input2" "Input3"
"2123232430000-z434342" "Team1" "Cust1" "20200512"
```

My aim is to add this file into postgresql table using python and Also I need to import only first 8 characters from first column and other columns as it. The other chars from the first column has to be omitted.
Kindly share some hints regarding this.

Comment: Do you want to limit the column names or the column values (or both)? And what have you tried so far?

Comment: only column values

Comment: Hint: read the file as text, or better with the csv module, use first line to build the column names, then for each line limit the strings to 8 characters (`[x[:8] for x in row]`) and insert the row in the PostgreSQL table. And show a honest attempt explaining where your are stuck if you want more help.

Comment: Thank you so much sir and I will update you after trying with your hint.

Comment: @SergeBallesta I tried as per your suggestion sir, But it was printing the complete file